# Why does it add new cells to my table after displaying data from db?

Tags: php, html

I don't understand why, if there is data from db to display, an empty cell is added to the right anyway. This code is supposed to show a school schedule.

I added a picture of how it looks.

Here is my code written in php:

```
    foreach ($hours as $hour) {
        echo "<tr><td>$hour</td>";
        for ($d = 1; $d <= 5; $d++) {
            $rowspan = 0;
            while ($schedule = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if (intval($schedule['day']) == $d && strtotime($schedule['beginning_time']) == strtotime($hour)) {
                    $end_time = $schedule['end_time'];
                    $rowspan = ceil((strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($hour)) / 900);
                    $cell_content = $schedule['subject'];
                    break; 
                }
                else $cell_content = '';
            }
            echo "<td" . ($rowspan > 1 ? " rowspan=\"$rowspan\"" : "") . ">$cell_content</td>";
            mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Because that `echo "<td" . ($rowspan...` will always run. If you want to break out of more than one level of loop [eg: 2] `break 2;` in that inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can use a flag to check whether you should add a new cell or not

```
foreach ($hours as $hour) {
        echo "<tr><td>$hour</td>";
        for ($d = 1; $d <= 5; $d++) {
            $rowspan = 0;
            $cell_added = false;
            while ($schedule = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if (intval($schedule['day']) == $d && strtotime($schedule['beginning_time']) == strtotime($hour)) {
                    $end_time = $schedule['end_time'];
                    $rowspan = ceil((strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($hour)) / 900);
                    $cell_content = $schedule['subject'];
                    echo "<td" . ($rowspan > 1 ? " rowspan=\"$rowspan\"" : "") . ">$cell_content</td>";
                    $cell_added = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!$cell_added) {
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
            mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```